# SQL Sum statement very slow

Tags: sql, vb.net

new to SQL and having trouble with this code.  It seems that the "SUM" function is just really slow.  It times out if the date range is more than 5 days. I have to loop thru this 115 times and cover a date range of 180 days.  Any ideas on what I can do to speed it up?  The string times out in the SQL Enterprise Manager as well. 
I've heard mention of using a "pivot" command, but don't know if that is the answer or how to implement it. TIA

```
strSQLRead = "SELECT SUM(BatchRecordDetail.BRD_Actual) AS LbsBatched, BatchRun.BAT_CoatingLBS AS     CoatingLbs, " _
& "BatchRun.BAT_ID AS RunID " _
& "FROM BatchRun " _
& "INNER JOIN BatchRecordMaster ON BatchRun.BAT_HmiRunID = BatchRecordMaster.BRM_BatchRunID " _
& "AND BatchRun.BAT_Area = BatchRecordMaster.BRM_Area " _
& "INNER JOIN BatchRecordDetail ON BatchRecordMaster.BRM_Area = BatchRecordDetail.BRD_Area " _
& "AND BatchRecordMaster.BRM_HmiBatchID = BatchRecordDetail.BRD_BatchRecordID " _
& "WHERE (BatchRun.BAT_ExtruderEnd BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & Format(ToDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")     & " 00:00:00', 102) " _
& "AND CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & Format(FromDate, "yyyy-MM-dd") & " 00:00:00', 102)) AND     (BatchRun.BAT_RunComplete = 1) " _
& "AND BatchRun.BAT_FormulaCode = '" & sFormula(i) & "'" _
& "GROUP BY BatchRun.BAT_FormulaCode,BatchRun.BAT_ID, BatchRun.BAT_CoatingLBS " _
& "HAVING (BatchRun.BAT_CoatingLBS Is Not Null)"
```

Here is the string as trapped in code.  Just wondering if anyone had any ideas.  thx

```
SELECT Sum(batchrecorddetail.brd_actual) AS LbsBatched, 
       batchrun.bat_coatinglbs           AS CoatingLbs, 
       batchrun.bat_id                   AS RunID 
FROM   batchrun 
       INNER JOIN batchrecordmaster 
               ON batchrun.bat_hmirunid = batchrecordmaster.brm_batchrunid 
                  AND batchrun.bat_area = batchrecordmaster.brm_area 
       INNER JOIN batchrecorddetail 
               ON batchrecordmaster.brm_area = batchrecorddetail.brd_area 
                  AND batchrecordmaster.brm_hmibatchid = 
                      batchrecorddetail.brd_batchrecordid 
WHERE  ( batchrun.bat_extruderend BETWEEN 
         CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-06-26 00:00:00', 102) 
                AND 
                CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-06-26 00:00:00' 
                , 102) ) 
       AND ( batchrun.bat_runcomplete = 1 ) 
       AND batchrun.bat_formulacode = '3100007' 
GROUP  BY batchrun.bat_formulacode, 
          batchrun.bat_id, 
          batchrun.bat_coatinglbs 
HAVING ( batchrun.bat_coatinglbs IS NOT NULL )
```

I can't post pics cause I don't have enough reputation points.
How would I display what else is needed to help answer the question?

Comment: This is impossible to read.  Please post the string value itself after it is constructed.  Also, without providing more detail about your tables, indexes, etc., there is no way for someone to know determine what the issue is.

Comment: Posted that above in my original question.

Comment: We'll still need to know table column types and indexes to get any insight.

Comment: A `HAVING` clause usually refers to an aggregate column, so I think `batchrun.bat_coatinglbs IS NOT NULL` should be in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL Server execution plan for the query?

Comment: Could you index `batchrun.bat_formulacode` so you aren't comparing strings? If not, moving it to a `JOIN` might reduce the number of string comparisons.